# Converting a result from mysqli_stmt_fetch to an associative array that could be exported by a loop by mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, arrays, loops, mysqli

I have been trying to write two functions which fetch a result set by `mysqli_stmt_bind_result` and an associative array respectively. However, after referring to many different sources, I couldn't get my code to work when I am trying to output everything by the `do...while` loop. Here are my codes for the two functions:

```
<?php
/*$sql as string, query
$param as array, to be inserted
$conn as mysqli_conn
$db as string, database name
Return: result set
*/
function mysqli_prep_query($sql, $conn, $db, $param = array(), $type = "") {
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $db);
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    $num_param_sql = substr_count($sql, "?");
    if (is_array($param)) {
        $num_param = count($param);
    } else {
        if ($param == "") {
            $num_param = 0;
        } else {
            $num_param = 1;
        }
    }
    $strlen_type = strlen($type);
    if ($num_param_sql == $num_param && $num_param == $strlen_type) {
        $param_ref = array();
        $param_array = array($stmt, $type);
        if ($num_param > 0) {
            for ($i = 0 ; $i < $num_param ; $i++) {
                $param_array[] = &${"param" . $i};
            }
        }
        if (call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_param", $param_array)) {
            if ($num_param == 1) {
                $param0 = $param;
            } else if ($num_param > 1) {
                for ($i = 0 ; $i < $num_param ; $i++) {
                    ${"param" . $i} = $param[$i];
                }
            }
            $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            if ($execute) {
                if (strpos($sql, "INSERT") === FALSE && strpos($sql, "UPDATE") === FALSE && strpos($sql, "DELETE") === FALSE) {
                    if (mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt)) {
                        return $stmt;
                    } else {
                        die("Cannot store data." . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
                    }
                } else {
                    return TRUE;
                }
            } else {
                die ("Error: Cannot execute statement <br />" . var_dump($param_array) . "<br />" . $sql);
            }
        } else {
            die ("Error: Cannot call mysqli_stmt_bind_param function. <br />" . var_dump($param_array));
        }
    } else {
        die("SQL error: The number of parameters is not equal to the number of slots.<br />num_param_sql=" . $num_param_sql . "<br />num_param=" . $num_param . "<br />strlen_type=" . $strlen_type . "<br />error_sql: " . $sql);

    }
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

function sd_mysqli_stmt_fetch_assoc($result) {
    $resultRwArray = array();
    $paramArray = array($result);
    do {
        $paramArray[]  =& $resultRwArray[$fields->name];
    } while ($fields = mysqli_fetch_field($raw_fieldData));

    if (mysqli_stmt_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        call_user_func_array("mysqli_stmt_bind_result",$paramArray);
        $rwFinalArray = array();
        while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)) {
            foreach ($resultRwArray as $key => $value) {
                $rwArray[$key] = $value;
            }
            array_push($rwFinalArray, $rwArray);
        }
        return $rwFinalArray;
    } else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
?>
```

How should I change my codes to make it possible for the second function to output an associative array that can generate output of all data selected by using the `do...while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: use PDO

```
function pdo_prep_query($conn, $sql, $param = array()) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($param);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Now you can get your data using either while or foreach loop:

```
$stmt = pdo_prep_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM users LIMIT ?,?", [0,10]);
while($row = $stmt->fetch())
{
    echo $user['name'];
}
```

Comment: I have two questions following that: 1. Can I use PDO with procedural style or it is a must to use object oriented? 2. Is there any way to solve the problem ysing the stmt commands? Thanks!

Comment: no, there is no procedural way to use PDO. Yes it's possible to solve your problem but you'd better forget the idea.

Comment: Why is stmt not recommended here?

Comment: The code you have to deal with at the moment is not convincing enough?

Comment: Here is a [PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo)  I wrote, which can help you, as well as a [wrapper class](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/pdo_wrapper) which you can use as a better substitution for your function